# I'm getting an error when i create a new project after updating Android Studio to 2.3

Tags: android

here is the log i got

```
com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject/root/build.gradle.ftl" in line 28, column 10:
                Lexical error: encountered "i" (105), after "#".
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling this FreemarketUtils thing? Maybe it's not compatible with the new version.

Comment: how to disabling this.

Comment: I don't know as I've never even heard of it. But it seems to be causing you issues and it's not part of a standard build; you would have had to install it or someone else did.

Comment: It says it's a template so maybe try looking in the templates section in the settings...

Comment: OK，thanks.I solved it.
I have previously replaced Android Studio's new project template

Comment: ok I added the comment as an answer. Please accept it since it solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suggests and error in the "FreemakerUtils" template. Try looking in the templates section in the settings and disable the offending template.